# Passing multiple values using

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to pass multiple values in single column of database.

I have two tables (Schedule & Days). In form I select days when I select multiple days then I should add in db multiple. But it add only one day

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $schedule = new menu;
    $days = new day;

    $sensor = new sensor;
    $schedule->scheduleName = $request->name;
    $schedule->start_time = $request->start_time;
    $schedule->end_time = $request->end_time;
    $schedule->timestamps = false;
    $schedule->s_daytime = $request->s_daytime;
    $schedule->e_daytime = $request->e_daytime;
    $days->days = $request->days;
    $days->timestamps = false;
    $sensor->timestamps = false;
    $sensor->sensor = $request->sensor;
    $schedule->save();
    $days->schedule_id = $schedule->id;
    $days->save();
    $sensor->schedule_id = $schedule->id;
    $sensor->save();

    return view('store');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you can pass multiple days in an array and store the array in json format on your DB. here is the snippets.

````
         $days_list = $request->days_list;
           //for edit previous data 
               if(!empty($days->days_list)){     
                    $arr = json_decode($days->days_list);
                        if(in_array($request->days, $arr)){
                            $data['success'] = false;
                            $data['message'] = 'This Day is already on your schedule 
                            list.';
                            return $data;
                        }
                    array_push($arr, $days_list);
                    $days->days_list = json_encode($arr);  
        }
         // for adding new data
           else{
                $days->days_list = json_encode(array($request->days_list));
               }

             $days->save();

    ```
````